# How can I extract only items from array that share a key/value pair?

Tags: php, arrays

In simple terms, I have a main array that contains invoices (from all customers).

I want to try and split this out to return in a new array only invoice data from a particular customer.

Inside the main invoice array, there is a key/value pair called `customer_id`, which ontains the ID number of the customer.

I'm passing this in a function I'm creating so I can specify which customer I want to retrieve invoices for.

I've pulled this together, but it's always returning NULL and I'm not sure why.

```
// Get customer invoices
function get_customer_invoices($customer_id = null) {
    if($customer_id) {
        $output = array_filter(get_invoices(), function ($item) use ($customer_id) {
            if(stripos($item['customer_id'], $customer_id) !== false) {
                return $output;
            }
            return false;
        });
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Note: `get_invoices()` is the main function that gets all invoices from an API, and returns this:

```
array(88) {
    [0]=> array(32) {
        ["id"]=> int(800481)
        ["customer_id"]=> int(81136)
        // Remaining key/value pairs
    }
}
```

Why is this returning NULL? or is it not able to diagnose yet?

Comment: You need to return `true` from your `array_filter` function, not `$output`

Comment: post your main invoice array first

Comment: and `$output` must be returned from outer function.

Comment: @Nick How do I return the output from the array so I can use the function elsewhere?

Comment: you can just put `return $output;` after the call to `array_filter`

Comment: Yeah I did think that, but this is dumping out a blank array, when it should have elements inside it. I can't post my main invoice array, as it contains customer info, but I'll try and create a dummy version.

Comment: Did you change the `array_filter` function? that should solve your problem...

Comment: Yeah, so it returns true not $output now, but the resulting array is empty still. Let me add an example of the main array I'm filtering from.

Comment: Hi @Nick so I've shown a small excerpt from the main array. I've noticed it starts with an [0] index, (I've taken the first invoice from the array). Do I need to go deeper into the array in my function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplified version of your code is:

```
function get_customer_invoices($customer_id = null) {
    if ($customer_id) {
        // return result of `array_filter` from `get_customer_invoices` function
        return array_filter(get_invoices(), function ($item) use ($customer_id) {
            // array_filter's callback should return `true` or `false` 
            return (stripos($item['customer_id'], $customer_id) !== false);
        });
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Update**: as your data sample shows that `customer_id` is int, I suppose it is better to compare int instead of strings. In this case filter function will be:

```
return array_filter(get_invoices(), function ($item) use ($customer_id) {
    // array_filter's callback should return `true` or `false` 
    return $item['customer_id'] === $customer_id;
});
```

Sample fiddle [here](https://3v4l.org/B1Siu).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, in simplifying it, I love that. The result is the same as the comments above, it returns an empty array. So I would suspect there's a problemw ith how I'm calling the main array. however if I do a var_dump(get_invoices()), I get the excerpt that I've added in my question. Any leads in there to go by?

Comment: I don't know why you compare `int` customer id value as string with `stripos`. I can recommend to cast ints to strings (which I think is nonsense) or replace `stripos` with simple `==/===`.

Comment: think you ought to update your answer with this new version as it works well